# Double suggestions on comment

Tags: bug, design, comments

Problem:

[image]

Question: [How do researchers ask others for comments and advices for their research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104442/14341)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that there are two accounts with the same display name and they both commented under your question. It might be the same user who created two accounts (maybe they lost the credentials of the first account): it's not forbidden.

I added a comment suggesting the possibility to merge the accounts, if they wish.